# OVER clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

What is the meaning of the OVER clause in Oracle?

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Comment: oh god no one likes the Oracle manual.  Stackoverflow for the ELI5 explanation everytime!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `OVER` clause specifies the partitioning, ordering and window "over which" the analytic function operates.

**Example #1: calculate a moving average**

```
AVG(amt) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)

date   amt   avg_amt
=====  ====  =======
1-Jan  10.0  10.5
2-Jan  11.0  17.0
3-Jan  30.0  17.0
4-Jan  10.0  18.0
5-Jan  14.0  12.0
```

It operates over a moving window (3 rows wide) over the rows, ordered by date.

**Example #2: calculate a running balance**

```
SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

date   amt   sum_amt
=====  ====  =======
1-Jan  10.0  10.0
2-Jan  11.0  21.0
3-Jan  30.0  51.0
4-Jan  10.0  61.0
5-Jan  14.0  75.0
```

It operates over a window that includes the current row and all prior rows.

Note: for an aggregate with an `OVER` clause specifying a sort `ORDER`, the default window is `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to `CURRENT ROW`, so the above expression may be simplified to, with the same result:

```
SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY date)
```

**Example #3: calculate the maximum within each group**

```
MAX(amt) OVER (PARTITION BY dept)

dept  amt   max_amt
====  ====  =======
ACCT   5.0   7.0
ACCT   7.0   7.0
ACCT   6.0   7.0
MRKT  10.0  11.0
MRKT  11.0  11.0
SLES   2.0   2.0
```

It operates over a window that includes all rows for a particular dept.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/122

Comment: Could you explain how OVER() works when used without argument?

Comment: No argument means it ranges over the entire result set.

Comment: Why in your first example does it calculate the previous from the first row as zero? Is that something you can change?

Comment: Hi k9b, it says "1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING" which is a window spanning up to 3 records - but the window never implies that there MUST be 3 records. It finds only two records, and calculates the average over those two records. Note: there was a copy-and-paste error which I'll fix.

Answer (score 34):

You can use it to transform some aggregate functions into analytic:

```
SELECT  MAX(date)
FROM    mytable
```

will return `1` row with a single maximum,

```
SELECT  MAX(date) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM    mytable
```

will return all rows with a running maximum.

Comment: You make a very good point about transforming aggregate functions into analytic ones. That's one way I never thought about it.

Answer (score 20):

It's part of the [Oracle analytic functions](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use OVER is to have a result column in your select operate on another "partition", so to say.

This:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    ssn, 
    case 
      when ( count(*) over (partition by ssn) ) > 1      
      then 1
      else 0
    end AS hasDuplicateSsn
FROM table;
```

returns 1 in hasDuplicateSsn for each row whose ssn is shared by another row. Great for making "tags" for data for different error reports and such.