# In which OracleSQL versions does OVER clause exists?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

In which version of Oracle is over clause is present? What is the purpose of this clause?

Comment: Window functions (aka "analytical functions") were introduced in Oracle 8.1: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/function.htm#81409

Comment: It should have been made duplicate. I have mentioned the original question in the below answer.

Comment: @Biswabid: the question you linked to asks _what_ that is. Shyam is asking in which version they are available.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : It asks the Purpose of this clause also, thats why i suggested the below answer.(which is the original question)

Answer (score 2):

The OVER clause specifies the partitioning, ordering & window "over which" the analytic function operates
Reference: 
[OVER clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle)

Comment: Thanks @Biswabid. Thereby, the OVER clause defines a window or user-defined and specified set of rows within a query result set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the window. We can use the OVER clause with functions to compute aggregated values.