# SQL statement to update a column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update

I have a Table T1 with following values

[image: Table]

I need a result table with additional column which is the average of upto date.
i.e.,

`x1= 1000.45`

`x2= (1000.45+2000.00)/2`

`x3= (1000.45+2000.00+3000.50)/3`

`x4= (1000.45+2000.00+3000.50+4000.24)/4`

The result table should look like the following:

[image: expected result]

I need to write SQL statement in Oracle database to add a column to result table with column values x1, x2, x3, x4.

Comment: "I need to write SQL statement" yeah cool, so what have you written?

Comment: @Gonzalo Thank u for editing my question. I'm new here and does not know the format

Comment: See if [this article](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/rollingavg.html) gives you some ideas.

Comment: Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
We need sample data and desire output to find an answer faster, otherwise we will be wasting time guessing what you need. You also could create your schema with data using **http://www.sqlfiddle.com** . Even when pictures are cool is very hard to transcript so include code text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an analytic function for this.  My untested SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT
 date,
 division,
 sum_sales,
 AVG( sum_sales ) OVER ( ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )
FROM
 table;
```

`date` is a reserved word in Oracle, so if you are using that as your real column name you will need to include it in quotes.

Comment: @anwaar_hell No, there is no need for a GROUP BY with an analytic function.  There is not grouping because every original row is represented in the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date,division,sum_sales,avg(sum_sales) over ( order by sum_sales ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
from table
group by date,division,sum_sales
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AVG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions011.htm) function [OVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle) ordering by date. As each row is an aggregation result of *all* the preceding rows, you need to define the [window](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-analytic-aggregate.html) of the aggregation as [*UNBOUNDED* PRECEDING](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_windowing_clause.htm)

By following these guidelines, the resultant statement would be like:

```
SELECT date_d, 
       division, 
       sum_sales, 
       AVG(sum_sales) 
         over ( 
           ORDER BY date_d ROWS unbounded preceding ) avrg 
FROM   supplier;
```

You can test that in [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/945d6/3)

Good two pieces of information about analytical functions in these two articles:
[Introduction to Analytic Functions (Part 1)](http://allthingsoracle.com/introduction-to-analytic-functions-part-1-2/)
[Introduction to Analytic Functions (Part 2)](http://allthingsoracle.com/introduction-to-analytic-functions-part-2/)