# query Get Balances in Oracle table stock

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have sample data in oracle data table namely **STOKREWARD** table, i wanna get balance between quantity **IN** and quantity **OUT**.

[image]

i wanna get value **BALANCES** like this:

[image]

i try using query like this, but the result doesn't i want

```
SELECT STOKREWARD.NO, STOKREWARD.DODATE, STOKREWARD.REWARDNAME, STOKREWARD.NOTES,
STOKREWARD.QTYIN, STOKREWARD.QTYOUT,
(STOKREWARD.QTYIN- STOKREWARD.QTYOUT) AS BALANCES
FROM STOKREWARD
ORDER BY STOKREWARD.NO ASC
```

this query gives result:

[image]

anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SUM() OVER`:

```
SELECT NO, DODATE, CODE, REWARDNAME, NOTES, QTYIN, QTYOUT,
    SUM (QTYIN - QTYOUT) OVER (ORDER BY DODATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS BALANCES
FROM STOKREWARD
```

Comment: can u explain me what is the meaning of `SUM (QTYIN - QTYOUT) OVER (ORDER BY DODATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` ?

Comment: This adds the previous balance to the current balance, for each row, and does this for all records in your table.  It is a running sum, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle) for more information.