# Returning multiple records whilst using a MAX function?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I'm not sure how to pose this question...  This SQL string returns 1 result (I think due to the MAX part) but I would like it to return all records.

So is there a way in one SQL statement to retrieve all the records related to the event (WHERE ticket_event_no = :id) AND find the MAX finish date of the recordset (find the latest ticket_finish dateof all tickets found)?

```
                SELECT 
                    MAX( ticket_finish ) AS cutOff, ticket_price, ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_qty, ticket_start, 
                    ticket_finish, ticket_max, ticket_type_no, ticket_min, ticket_order, ticket_fee
                FROM 
                    ticket 
                WHERE 
                    ticket_event_no = :id
                AND
                    ticket_hide = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a tag for which DBMS you are using.

Comment: @HepC this is most likely mysql, since the query has an aggregation function, but no `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to grab your max date with a subquery in your select list:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Max(ticket_finish) from ticket) as cutOff, 
    ticket_price, 
    ticket_id, 
    ticket_name, 
    ticket_qty, 
    ticket_start, 
    ticket_finish, 
    ticket_max, 
    ticket_type_no, 
    ticket_min,
    ticket_order, 
    ticket_fee
FROM ticket
WHERE 
    ticket_event_no = :id
    AND ticket_hide = 0
```

That will pull the max value of `ticket_finish` and populate it as `cutOff` in all rows.

Comment: Perfect - I removed the a. in the WHERE clause & it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
MAX( ticket_finish ) over () AS cutOff, 
ticket_price, ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_qty, ticket_start, 
ticket_finish, ticket_max, ticket_type_no, ticket_min, ticket_order, ticket_fee
FROM ticket 
WHERE ticket_event_no = :id AND ticket_hide = 0
```

Comment: Here it is explained quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle . The over specifies on which set you want to operate the aggregate function which is Max(ticket_finish). We want it to operate on the whole set, because we want the maximum of all terms, therefore we leave the bracket empty.

Comment: No joy...  MySql said: An alias was previously found. (near "cutOff" at position 46).   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() AS cutOff, ticket_price, ticket_id, ticket_name, ticket_qty, ticket_start, 
' at line 2

Comment: Further research says there is no OVER in MySql

Comment: You did not tag a DBMS before - I am sorry my solution work in the Oracle environment. Use then the solution above.