# Unable to get the SQL query working with DISTINCT and windows function

Tags: sql, distinct

I am not able to get this working because of the DISTINCT keyword

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS tweet_bucket,
    DISTINCT COUNT(user_id) AS users_num
FROM
    tweets
WHERE 
    tweet_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    user_id
```

I know if I remove the windows function and just put it as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COUNT(user_id) AS users_num
FROM 
    tweets
WHERE 
    tweet_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    user_id
```

it works

I cannot remove the windows function as I need to get a row_id using `ROW_NUMBER()`

Realy struggling, is there anyway of using the same logic and have the distinct?

Here is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE tweets 
(
    tweet_id INT,
    user_id INT,
    msg VARCHAR(500),
    tweet_date DATETIME
);
  
DROP TABLE tweets;
  
INSERT INTO tweets 
VALUES (214252, 111, "Am considering taking Tesla private at $420. Funding secured", '2021-12-30 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO tweets 
VALUES (739252, 111, "Despite the constant negative press covfefe", '2022-01-01 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO tweets 
VALUES (846402, 111, "Following @NickSinghTech on Twitter changed my life!", '2022-02-14 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO tweets 
VALUES (241425, 254, "If the salary is so competitive why won’t you tell me what it is?", '2022-03-01 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO tweets 
VALUES (231574, 148, "I no longer have a manager. I can't be managed", '2022-03-01 00:00:00');
  
SELECT * FROM tweets;

SELECT DISTINCT 
    COUNT(user_id) AS users_num,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS tweet_bucket
FROM 
    tweets
WHERE 
    tweet_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    user_id
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT must come first.  Just move the ROW_NUMBER call to after the DISTINCT.  I question whether you really want DISTINCT, however.  If you're actually counting distinct users then you might want COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), although I'm not sure that's entirely correct either because it doesn't make sense to count distinct user_id if you're grouping by user_id.  And it doesn't make sense to get distinct counts either

Comment: Also I question your terminology of row_id... using ROW_NUMBER() is not a method to obtain a row_id but instead just a row number based on the criteria such as the Order By or just the random order the database produced the dataset.  If you are looking to generate keys for a dataset to INSERT into a table or 'something' use an IDENTITY column which auto generates the next key for that field OR you can make use of SEQUENCES.

Comment: It works by putting DISTINCT before ROW_NUMBER . But I do not get the right answer. I was expecting none of the fields in users_num column will be repeated but that is not the case. However, if I remove ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS tweet_bucket it works perfectly i.e. I have tne column with no fields repeated but I do need the row_number column which is just a row id in asceding oder.

Comment: Also note, using ROW_NUMBER() is not something that you can rely on in order to produce the same number each time... new records in your database or a change in the query or Order By will result in different row numbers per the same records in the resultset.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. We don't know your data, and we don't know what you want...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I have put my data in a form. I am using sqlite

Comment: I have revised my question and put the dataI want to write a query to obtain a histogram of tweets posted per user in 2022. 
and Output the tweet count per user as the bucket, and then the number of Twitter users who fall into that bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in Oracle PL/SQL, maybe you should try `OVER(ORDER BY user_id)`.

sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(user_id) AS users_num, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY user_id) AS tweet_bucket
FROM tweets
WHERE tweet_date >= to_date('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY user_id
order by tweet_bucket
```

*May this post/answer also help to get a better understanding: [OVER clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle)*

Answer (score 0):

I get the right answer with a CTE

```
WITH HistogramTweets AS   (   SELECT   DISTINCT COUNT(user_id) AS
users_num   FROM tweets   WHERE tweet_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'  
GROUP BY user_id ) SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS tweet_bucket,
users_num FROM HistogramTweets
```