# Why does over() not return null

Tags: sql, oracle

If over() means it ranges over the entire result set, why it won't return null in "max(column) over()".

Is the reason about something like "null considered as int" concept?

[OVER clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1092120/22034288)

I have tried find official oracle document. Failed.

Tried google other discussion to  get some clue. Failed.

Tried test myself with result from adding different arguments to over() like max(c) over(partition by c), max(c) over(order by c) to figure out the mechanism. Failed

Comment: [All aggregate functions except COUNT(*), GROUPING, and GROUPING_ID ignore nulls](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848)

Comment: It doesn'make sense  max(c) over(partition by c). Normally if you want max(c), that has to be partitioned over some other column(s) than c.

Comment: Do you have some sample data and a runnable query with what you expected and what actual results you're getting? Because I'm really not sure what behaviour you're trying to ask about here is.

Comment: It will, if all values in the range are NULL

Comment: My bad. I used my phone to ask here. That's why I didn't put any data sample. MT0 got my point. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in the Oracle documentation for [Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848):

> All aggregate functions except `COUNT(*)`, `GROUPING`, and `GROUPING_ID` ignore `null`s. You can use the `NVL` function in the argument to an aggregate function to substitute a value for a `null`. `COUNT` and `REGR_COUNT` never return `null`, but return either a number or zero. For all the remaining aggregate functions, if the data set contains no rows, or contains only rows with `null`s as arguments to the aggregate function, then the function returns `null`.

When you look at the documentation for [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) it states:

> Analytic functions compute an aggregate value based on a group of rows. They differ from aggregate functions in that they return multiple rows for each group.

So an analytic function will follow exactly the same rules for `null` values as its equivalent aggregate version (and will ignore `null` values except in those documented cases); and will applying the aggregation over a window and return multiple rows.

---

For example, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  column_name NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (NULL);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(column_name) OVER () FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

| ID | MAX(COLUMN_NAME)OVER() |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* |
| 2 | *null* |

Then it outputs `null` as the data-set contains only rows with `null`s as arguments (exactly as per the documentation).

If you add a non-`null` row:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (42);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(column_name) OVER () FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

| ID | MAX(COLUMN_NAME)OVER() |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 |
| 2 | 42 |
| 3 | 42 |

Again, exactly as documented, the `null` values are ignored and the maximum of the non-`null` rows is returned.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r04Il9Ns)

Comment: I need to take time to read this, but I think you got what I want according your data sample. I should feed back on weekend. Thanks first

Comment: Sorry for unexpected delay. I thought there is a Subject or page "over()", and I didn't know about aggregate/analytic function. I learn tons of proper nouns. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what your expectation is as to the usage of null in over(partition by ...).
Below you may see an example of how partition by works when the column on which you partition has null values:

```
with t_data (code, val) as (
  select 'A', 13 from dual union all
  select 'A', 8 from dual union all
  select 'A', 0 from dual union all
  select 'B', 121 from dual union all 
  select 'B', 441 from dual union all 
  select '', 7 from dual union all 
  select '', 21 from dual
```

)
select code, val, max(val) over (partition by code)
from t_data;

The results should be clear enough.
If this is not satisfactory, please explain what you wish to achieve giving a sample of data and the expected results.

Comment: MT0 answer my wonder. Thanks